# How can i add overlap-add into this

Tags: fft, ifft, c, overlap-add

Im new to DSP and i wanna know how i can add overlap-add into this to remove artifacts.

```
#include <SoapySDR/Device.h>
#include <SoapySDR/Formats.h>
#include <stdio.h> //printf
#include <stdlib.h> //free
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <sndfile.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 65536
#define SAMPLE_RATE 2.4e6
#define CENTER_FREQUENCY 100e6
#define TARGET_FREQUENCY 100.3e6
#define BANDWIDTH 200e3


complex float buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
complex float output_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
float demodulated_sample[BUFFER_SIZE];
size_t buffer_index = 0;


// Global variables for FFTW plans and arrays
fftw_complex *in_global, *out_global;
fftw_plan p_global, p_inv_global;

void initialize_fftw(size_t length) {
    // Allocate memory for FFTW input and output arrays
    in_global = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * length);
    out_global = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * length);

    // Create FFTW plans
    p_global = fftw_plan_dft_1d(length, in_global, out_global, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    p_inv_global = fftw_plan_dft_1d(length, out_global, in_global, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
}

void cleanup_fftw() {
    // Cleanup
    fftw_destroy_plan(p_global);
    fftw_destroy_plan(p_inv_global);
    fftw_free(in_global);
    fftw_free(out_global);
}

// Big credits to HA7ILM for the FM Demodulation - This is very effecient and sounds great!
// https://github.com/ha7ilm/csdr
#define fmdemod_quadri_K 0.340447550238101026565118445432744920253753662109375
// this constant ensures proper scaling for qa_fmemod testcases for SNR calculation and more.
void fm_demodulate(complex float *in, float *out, size_t len)
{
    if (len == 10)
        return;

    complex float last_sample = {0, 0};
    float temp_dq[len];
    float temp_di[len];
    float temp[len];

    // Handle dq
    temp_dq[0] = cimagf(in[0]) - cimagf(last_sample);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        temp_dq[i] = cimagf(in[i]) - cimagf(in[i - 1]);
    }

    // Handle di
    temp_di[0] = crealf(in[0]) - crealf(last_sample);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        temp_di[i] = crealf(in[i]) - crealf(in[i - 1]);
    }

    // Output numerator
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        out[i] = crealf(in[i]) * temp_dq[i] - cimagf(in[i]) * temp_di[i];
    }

    // Output denominator
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        temp[i] = crealf(in[i]) * crealf(in[i]) + cimagf(in[i]) * cimagf(in[i]);
    }

    // Output division
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        out[i] = (temp[i]) ? fmdemod_quadri_K * out[i] / temp[i] : 0;
    }
}

int process_block(fftw_complex *fft_result, size_t length, complex float *output, float target_frequency) {
    // Copy FFT result to local array for processing
    fftw_complex *out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * length);
    memcpy(out, fft_result, sizeof(fftw_complex) * length);

    // Determine whether the target frequency is above or below the center frequency
    bool is_above_center = target_frequency >= CENTER_FREQUENCY;

    // Calculate the index range for the target frequency band
    size_t lower_index, upper_index;
    if (is_above_center) {
        lower_index = (size_t)((target_frequency - BANDWIDTH/2 - CENTER_FREQUENCY) / (SAMPLE_RATE / length));
        upper_index = (size_t)((target_frequency + BANDWIDTH/2 - CENTER_FREQUENCY) / (SAMPLE_RATE / length));
    } else {
        lower_index = (size_t)((CENTER_FREQUENCY - (target_frequency + BANDWIDTH/2)) / (SAMPLE_RATE / length));
        upper_index = (size_t)((CENTER_FREQUENCY - (target_frequency - BANDWIDTH/2)) / (SAMPLE_RATE / length));
    }

    // Zero out all frequencies outside the target band
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lower_index; i++) {
        out[i][0] = 0;
        out[i][1] = 0;
    }
    for (size_t i = upper_index + 1; i < length; i++) {
        out[i][0] = 0;
        out[i][1] = 0;
    }

    // Execute inverse FFT
    fftw_execute_dft(p_inv_global, out, in_global);

    // Copy FFTW output array to output buffer and decimate
    size_t decimation_factor = SAMPLE_RATE / BANDWIDTH;
    size_t j = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i += decimation_factor) {
        output[j] = in_global[i][0] + in_global[i][1] * I;
        j++;
    }

    // Cleanup
    fftw_free(out);
    return j;
}

void execute_fft(complex float *input, size_t length, fftw_complex *output) {
    // Copy input data to FFTW input array
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        in_global[i][0] = crealf(input[i]);
        in_global[i][1] = cimagf(input[i]);
    }

    // Execute FFT
    fftw_execute(p_global);

    // Copy FFT result to output array
    memcpy(output, out_global, sizeof(fftw_complex) * length);
}

// Main processing loop
void process_data(complex float *data, size_t total_size, SNDFILE *file) {
    complex float windowed_data[total_size];
    complex float output_data[total_size];
    fftw_complex *fft_result = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * BUFFER_SIZE);
        execute_fft(data, total_size, fft_result);
        int received_data = process_block(fft_result, total_size, output_buffer, TARGET_FREQUENCY);
        fm_demodulate(output_buffer, demodulated_sample, received_data);
        sf_writef_float(file, demodulated_sample, received_data);

    
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t length;

    //enumerate devices
    SoapySDRKwargs *results = SoapySDRDevice_enumerate(NULL, &length);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("Found device #%d: ", (int)i);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < results[i].size; j++)
        {
            printf("%s=%s, ", results[i].keys[j], results[i].vals[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    SoapySDRKwargsList_clear(results, length);

    //create device instance
    SoapySDRKwargs args = {};
    SoapySDRKwargs_set(&args, "driver", "rtlsdr");

    SoapySDRDevice *sdr = SoapySDRDevice_make(&args);
    SoapySDRKwargs_clear(&args);

    if (sdr == NULL)
    {
        printf("SoapySDRDevice_make fail: %s\n", SoapySDRDevice_lastError());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


    //apply settings
    if (SoapySDRDevice_setSampleRate(sdr, SOAPY_SDR_RX, 0, 2.4e6) != 0)
    {
        printf("setSampleRate fail: %s\n", SoapySDRDevice_lastError());
    }
    if (SoapySDRDevice_setFrequency(sdr, SOAPY_SDR_RX, 0, 100e6, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("setFrequency fail: %s\n", SoapySDRDevice_lastError());
    }

    //setup a stream (complex floats)
    SoapySDRStream *rxStream = SoapySDRDevice_setupStream(sdr, SOAPY_SDR_RX, SOAPY_SDR_CF32, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (rxStream == NULL)
    {
        printf("setupStream fail: %s\n", SoapySDRDevice_lastError());
        SoapySDRDevice_unmake(sdr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    SoapySDRDevice_activateStream(sdr, rxStream, 0, 0, 0); //start streaming

    //create a re-usable buffer for rx samples
    complex float buff[1024];

    SF_INFO info;
    info.samplerate = 200e3;
    info.channels = 1;
    info.format = SF_FORMAT_WAV | SF_FORMAT_PCM_16;
    SNDFILE *file = sf_open("output.wav", SFM_WRITE, &info);

    initialize_fftw(BUFFER_SIZE);


    //receive some samples
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        void *buffs[] = {buff}; //array of buffers
        int flags; //flags set by receive operation
        long long timeNs; //timestamp for receive buffer
        int ret = SoapySDRDevice_readStream(sdr, rxStream, buffs, 1024, &flags, &timeNs, 1000000);

        // Check for errors in readStream
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading stream: %s\n", SoapySDR_errToStr(ret));
            continue;  // Skip to next iteration on error
        }
        // Copy received samples from buff to buffer
        memcpy(buffer + buffer_index, buff, ret * sizeof(complex float));
        buffer_index += ret;
        if (buffer_index >= BUFFER_SIZE) {


            process_data(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, file);

            buffer_index = 0;
        }
    }

    sf_close(file);


    //shutdown the stream
    SoapySDRDevice_deactivateStream(sdr, rxStream, 0, 0); //stop streaming
    SoapySDRDevice_closeStream(sdr, rxStream);

    //cleanup device handle
    SoapySDRDevice_unmake(sdr);

    printf("Done\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```